# How to overload react props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

It is possible to make one component that allows different sets of props?

For example, if I pass prop "name" then function will also returns "name".

```
<SameComponent name="yes" onChange={(name: string) => {}} />
<SameComponent onChange={() => {}} />
```

without having to check the value like

```
const change = (name: string | undefined) => {
    if (!name) return;
}

<SameComponent name="yes" onChange={change} />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't make one component to take different set of props but what you can do is use conditional rendering.

you can only render component that satisfy your condition.